# SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection erro Websphere 8

Tags: java, ssl

Estou com o seguinte erro ao subir uma aplicação usando WAS 8.0 e Eclipse Mars, pesquisei uma série de coisas na internet, mas não encontrei nada que ajudasse, tentei até a alterar a versão da JDK

Ou coisas como:

https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftworkssl.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566240/websphere-7-ssl-error-that-never-goes-away-no-matter-what-i-do

```
SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.ibm.jsse2.c.a(c.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:32)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:275)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:29)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:295)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
```

Não consegui encontrar uma solução até agora, se alguém puder me ajudar desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era a versão da JDK, estava usando a 8, tive que voltar para a versão 7 mesma, alterando assim o arquivo eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
/Program Files/Java/jre1.7.0_80/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Isso fez o projeto "subir"